# Apache RewriteRule based on the year

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

we want to redirect the urls based on the year to the archive dir

url 1: http://example.com/docs/asd_20140101.html to  http://example.com/docs/**2014**/asd_20140101.html

url 2: http://example.com/docs/asd_20150101.html to  http://example.com/docs/**2015**/asd_20150101.html

based on the url the files has to be redirected.

thanks
arasu.b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different regex variations you could use to accomplish this, but something like the following may work:

RewriteRule ^(/docs)(/asd_)([0-9]{4}+)(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/$3$2$3$4 [R]

that's just one example and might need to be tailored further to your needs / environment.

Comment: thanks for your support, this was almost what i have done. but we are stuck at the rule get repeated in loop.

http://example.com/docs/asd_20150101.html to http://example.com/docs/2015/2015/2015/2015/2015/2015/2015/2015/2015/2015/2015/asd_20150101.html